# setInterval is returning the same interval id, when I change browser tabs

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have implemented socket.io in my node app and also in my react app. Following suggestions from another question i found here, I implemented my own heartbeat resetter. It works, when I stop the server and restart it, the client reconnects, but as soon as I change tabs on chrome, the socket.on("ping") console.logs the same interval id twice. why is that? my code is:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket && user && socketPingInterval) {
      socket.on("ping", () => {
        console.log("ping received");
        console.log(socketPingInterval);
        clearInterval(socketPingInterval);

        const intervalId = setInterval(() => refreshPing(socket), 1000 * 5);

        if (intervalId !== socketPingInterval) {
          console.log("unique interval id", intervalId);
          setSocketPingInterval(intervalId);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        socket.off("ping");
      };
    }
  }, [socket, user, socketPingInterval]);
```

socket is only set when user is, so the if statement always passes, thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by saying:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket && user && socketPingInterval) {
      socket.on("ping", () => {
        console.log("ping received");
        console.log(socketPingInterval);
        clearInterval(socketPingInterval);

        const intervalId = setInterval(() => refreshPing(socket), 1000 * 5);

        if (intervalId !== socketPingInterval) {
          console.log("unique interval id", intervalId);
          setSocketPingInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        socket.off("ping");
      };
    }
  }, [socket, user, socketPingInterval]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was that I was passing an anonymous function, instead of function reference. So the correct answer is this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket && user && socketPingInterval) {
      let handler = () => {
        console.log("ping from server", socketPingInterval);
        if (socketConnectionLost) {
          setSocketConnectionLost(false);
          socket.emit("reconnect");
        }

        clearInterval(socketPingInterval);
        const intervalId = setInterval(refreshPing, 1000 * 11);
        setSocketPingInterval(intervalId);
      };

      socket.on("ping-client", handler);

      return () => {
        socket.off("ping-client", handler);
      };
    }
  }, [socket, user, socketPingInterval]);
```